# Determining the value of a point in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to have the points in a chart change color if they are within certain value paramaters (i.e., >1 is green, <1 is red, anything else is blue).  I cannot determine how to get VBA to give me the value of any given point.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136194/change-the-point-color-in-chart-excel-vba), previously answered, the answer (very helpful in other ways) indicates that points(num).value will return the value at the point. However, I am getting an error message doing this, and nowhere else online or in the VBA help can I find a method that corresponds to this.  Has anyone else had any success with this?

Here's the snippet of code giving me trouble:

```
For Count = 1 To 7
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("ChartName").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Count).Value > 1 Then
    '... do stuff
```

Because of the way the data are stored in the dataset, it would definitely be better to get the value from the chart directly.  I could figure out a workaround using the dataset itself, but I would rather avoid that.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Could you post a more complete version of your code?  Also, I removed your apology; it's actually Stack Overflow rules that if you have a new question, you should post a new question instead of asking in an existing one, so good on you for that.

Comment: It says "Run-Time Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method".  Seems pretty straightforward... i was mostly wondering if the same property existed, simply with a different name. There wasn't much more to the code, since I figured out that this was for sure the part that was giving me the error. I didn't get around to actually implementing the "do stuff" yet, but it wouldn't even open, for example, a "msgbox" confirming it had passed the line. And by the way, in this particular instance the value of the point was indeed greater than 1!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, p As Point
Dim vals, x As Integer

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

    vals = s.Values

    For x = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
      If vals(x) > 10 Then
        With s.Points(x)
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
      End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I've adapted it to what I need it to do (read: complicated and dirtied it up); what I can't understand now is why it is doing what I need on all but one of my charts.  I've posted my code at http://pastebin.com/yTqEnw01 if you want to take a look.  Basically, it's color coding every chart correctly, but chart "2" is always green; the colors never change.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the whole workbook: didn't see any obvious issues with your code.

Comment: I think it ended up being a problem with Excel not recognizing the chart title.  That is, I named the charts "1", "2", "3", etc., so that I could iterate through them, but VBA was acting as if I was talking about chart(1) as opposed to chart("1").  I added a "case select" to spit out an actual chart name and it fixed the problem; also made the code more legible to people more novice than me.  Thanks for your help; I would upvote but my reputation score is not high enough yet!

Comment: No problem: please "accept" the answer though (by clicking on the checkmark).  This helps anyone who comes along later with a similar question to find an answer.

Comment: It's a shame `Point.Value` does not exist.  This approach is just as good once you get it written out.  Used the technique here to [delete data labels based on value](http://superuser.com/questions/920162/hide-data-label-containing-series-name-if-value-is-zero/920246#920246).