# Return value of a point in a series in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to return the value of a data point in a chart to compare it to a known value and display a data label if it is over a certain threshold in PowerPoint.

This post explains how to do it in excel, but .values doesn't appear to be in the ppt object model.

[Determining the value of a point in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122329/determining-the-value-of-a-point-in-excel-vba)

I know there is .points(i), but that doesn't seem to be able to return the actual value of the point.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me

```
Dim chartSeries As Series
Set chartSeries = chartShape.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
seriesValue = chartSeries.Values(1)
```