# Does point have value properties

Tags: vba, point

When I was searching, I recognized a previous post: [Change the Point Color in chart excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136194/change-the-point-color-in-chart-excel-vba). It was said we can get the value of a point in a chart by using this: .Points(PointNumber).Value. Does point have value property? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You can easily check by typing "Point.Value" and see if it complains.

Answer (score 0):

No, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174283(v=office.11).aspx?query=point+object+vba

What you want is the `values` or `xvalues` of the `series`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840677(v=office.15).aspx