# Changing colour of a chart series based on conditions using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code using vba so that a series on a chart is formatted based on certain criteria. My coding is as follows

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim NPOINTS As Integer
Dim NVAL(1000) As Range, XVAL(1000) As Range, YVAL(1000) As Range
Dim Score(1000) As Range
Sheets("Scenario").Select
Range("B4").Select

NPOINTS = Worksheets("Scenario").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Set Scenario = Worksheets("Scenario")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select

 NVAL0 = "B3"
 XVAL0 = "C3"
 YVAL0 = "D3"
 SCORE0 = "E3"
 For i = 1 To NPOINTS
       Set Score(i) = Cells(Range(SCORE0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(SCORE0).Column)
       Set NVAL(i) = Cells(Range(NVAL0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(NVAL0).Column)
       Set XVAL(i) = Cells(Range(XVAL0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(XVAL0).Column)
       Set YVAL(i) = Cells(Range(YVAL0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(YVAL0).Column)
       Scorei = Score(i).Value
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = NVAL(i)
       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = XVAL(i)
       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = YVAL(i)
       If Scorei <= 10 >= 0 Then
          ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Interior.Colour = _
             RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
       ElseIf Scorei <= 30 >= 11 Then
          ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Interior.Colour = _
             RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
       ElseIf Scorei <= 60 >= 31 Then
          ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Interior.Colour = _
             RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
       ElseIf Scorei <= 100 >= 61 Then
          ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Interior.Colour = _
             RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
       Else
          MsgBox "ERROR :- Score out of range"
       End If


 Next
 With ActiveChart
    'chart name
   .HasTitle = False

    'X axis name
   .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
   .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "INFLUENCE"
    'y-axis name
   .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
   .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "IMPORTANCE"
   .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
   .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Priority Chart"
End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately when I run it, it fails with "Object doesn't support this property or method and then when I press Debug it highlights the following line

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Interior.Colour = _
             RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
```

Where am I going wrong?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

just

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB =RGB(0, 255, 0)
```

Comment: when I do this, It only seems to affect the border of the data point. Any way of making this work to fill it?

Comment: what kind of chart?

Comment: It is a scatter chart (xlXYScatter)

Comment: this above should work for fill. If you want it affect also a border ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).format.fill.ForeColor.RGB =

Answer (score 0):

The `.Points()` is a collection. 
You will need to cycle through all its elements and change the color one by one.
The left most point is `.Points(1)`, the right most point is `.Points.count`
as per: [Change the Point Color in chart excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136194/change-the-point-color-in-chart-excel-vba)

Also there is no such thing as interior colour for points.
There are 4 relevant options as per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/point-object-excel

- MarkerBackgroundColor
- MarkerBackgroundColorIndex
- MarkerForegroundColor
- MarkerForegroundColorIndex

As per comment from Jon Peltier it is not recommended to make use of the `colorindex` as this is a legacy from excel <2003

Comment: Don't use the `ColorIndex` properties, stick to the `Color` properties. `ColorIndex` is legacy from Excel 2003 and earlier, and merely confuses the Excel color system even further.